# Invoking only the last registered event handler

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling, delegates

We are building a game and we have a dialog system. Dialogs may open and stack on top of one another.

When every dialog opens, it registers itself to handle the BackButtonPressed event:

```
AppHelper.OnBackPressed += HandleBackPressed;
```

When the dialog closed, it unhooks from the event:

```
AppHelper.OnBackPressed -= HandleBackPressed;
```

The problem is, we'd like the event to raise the event handler of the **active dialog only** (the active dialog is the last one registered to the event.

A proposed solution was to:

1. Manually create the *add* and *remove* methods for the event
2. Keeping registered handlers in a list.
3. When raising the event, call the last handler in the list

Here's an example in code, **is this the proper way of doing this?**

```
private static List<BackPressed> backPressed = new List<BackPressed>();

public static event BackPressed OnBackPressed
{
    add
    {
        backPressed.Add(value);
    }
    remove
    {
        if(backPressed.Contains(value))
        {
            backPressed.Remove(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Raising the event:

```
backPressed[backPressed.Count - 1].Invoke();
```

Comment: BTW, did you mean `AppHelper.OnBackPressed += HandleBackPressed;`? Or is `HandleBackPressed()` a method that returns the handler delegate?

Comment: first option. i corrected my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a reasonable way to implement the event. Another would be use the normal even implementation (without explicit `add` and `remove`) and get the last subscriber using [`GetInvocationList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist).

But I think the fundamental problem here is that what you want doesn't really behave like an event, so it probably shouldn't be an event.

What I would probably do is to make the abstraction something like “a collection of open `Dialog`s”, not “a collection of delegates that are going to be invoked when the back button is pressed”.

That way, you can easily access the top-most open `Dialog` and invoke its `HandleBackPressed()` method. But you could also use it for other purposes. So this would make your code more flexible, without adding much complexity.

Comment: The only issue is we have lots of code that uses this current "pattern". The solution i described keeps the fix in a single location instead of having to change all client code. If we had more time we would probably go for something like you suggested.